# Create ranges of dates from a single array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

How can I make ranges of dates (from the newest to the oldest) from one array of dates?

I have this array of dates:

```
["2017-11-16T12:12:50.323Z", "2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z", "2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z", "2017-11-13T06:56:21.332Z"]
```

And I want to have the following ranges of dates result:

```
["2017-11-16T12:12:50.323Z", "2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z"]
["2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z", "2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z"]
["2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z", "2017-11-13T06:56:21.332Z"]
```

I want to achieve this in JavaScript

Comment: You can create sort this array and then loop over it and create intermediate arrays. But this is obvious stuff. You must have tried it. Can you show us how far have you reached?

Comment: You mean you want to split the array by couples? Meaning 1st and 2nd values are one array, 3rd and 4th are second array and so on? If not, based on what do you want to split the first array?

Comment: @Dropout well, the idea is, if the dates are in disorder, sort them from the newest to the oldest and then split them by couples. I think that is the main idea to achieve what I want

Comment: @maoooricio I've submitted an answer, I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dates are ordered, you can iterate with for loop up to the last item, and [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) each pair:

```js
var dates = ["2017-11-16T12:12:50.323Z", "2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z", "2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z", "2017-11-13T06:56:21.332Z"];

var ranges = [];
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length - 1; i++) {
  ranges.push(dates.slice(i, i + 2));
}

console.log(ranges);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the actual element of the array and the next for a new item of the result with a [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) pattern which returns the next item for the next loop as actual item.

```js
var data = ["2017-11-16T12:12:50.323Z", "2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z", "2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z", "2017-11-13T06:56:21.332Z"],
    result = [];
    
data.sort((a, b) => b > a || -(b < a)); // desc

data.reduce((a, b) => (result.push([a, b]), b));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Just a heads up, your callback for sorting can just be `(a,b) => b - a`

Comment: @Andrew, is that new for strings?

Comment: In all honesty, I have no clue why it works for strings nor how long this has been possible.

Comment: @Andrew, the result of the operation is `NaN`, because the strings are not convertable to a number. `sort` treats `NaN` as zero.

Comment: I literally just tried it myself and you're right. This only works in this case because of type coercion with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = ["2017-11-16T12:12:50.323Z", "2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z", "2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z", "2017-11-13T06:56:21.332Z"];

var paired = data.sort().slice(0, -1).map(function(d, i) {
  return [d, data[i+1]];
})

console.log(paired);
```

Or using es6 you could do it in one line:

```js
let data = ["2017-11-16T12:12:50.323Z", "2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z", "2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z", "2017-11-13T06:56:21.332Z"];

let paired = data.sort().slice(0, -1).map((d, i) => [d, data[i+1]])

console.log(paired)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't need any advanced sorting, you can just use the default `.sort()` function which javascript provides.

```
var datesSorted = dates.sort();
```

Splitting into pairs can be done in a cycle, because JavaScript doesn't provide any direct "split array into pairs" function.

The final script should look something like this:

```
var dates = ["2017-11-16T12:12:50.323Z", "2017-11-15T16:13:24.219Z", "2017-11-14T16:13:55.449Z", "2017-11-13T06:56:21.332Z"];
var datesSorted = dates.sort();

var datePairs = function(datesSorted) {
    var pairs = [];
    for (var i=0 ; i<datesSorted.length ; i+=2) { //iterate by two
        if (datesSorted[i+1] !== undefined) { //check if a date has a "pair"
            pairs.push ([datesSorted[i], datesSorted[i+1]]); //if it does, push them both
        } else {
            pairs.push ([datesSorted[i]]);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
};
```

You're array of date arrays should now be stored in `datePairs`.

Comment: Please provide feedback if you feel the need to downvote. Thanks.